# How to enable doc_values in Elasticsearch 1.7 by default?

Tags: elasticsearch, config

I'm using ES 1.7 and want to enable doc_values by default.

Is there a config parameter I can set in elasticsearch.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Doc values can be enabled for numeric, date, Boolean, binary, and geo-point fields, and for `not_analyzed` string fields. Doc values are enabled per field in the field mapping and the easiest way to do this overall in your cluster is to define index templates for your indices and cover there those fields you want to enable doc_values for.